# GITLAB bash: line 147: mkdir: command not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Previously my job was running, but suddenly it started giving the following error message

```
bash: line 147: mkdir: command not found
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
default:

  tags:
    - $RUNNER_LABEL_AZ

stages:

  - unittests

unitTests:

  stage: unittests
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew test

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./**/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml

    when: always

    reports:
      junit: ./**/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml
```

I am using a shell executer

I am not able to find any help as -- 'bash: line 147: mkdir: command not found' where it is pointig

Comment: I used Specific runner, which a linux runner box (working as a runner)

Comment: So you don't know which shell script contains a `mkdir` command at line 147?

Comment: Please use a code block to format code, such as YAML file. That makes it far more readable.

Comment: Yes i dont know where that script is

Comment: And what is `gradlew`? The YAML file suggests it's a script, but what type of script?